# What do Package Statistics in Nuget.org mean?

Tags: nuget

I was looking at [my nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AbTestMaster) statistics on nuget.org and I can see that the vast majority of downloads are from "Unknown" operations via "Other" clients.

Does anyone know what they mean?

p.s. is this the right SE site for the question? I couldn't find/create nuget tag in others.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that unknown operations performed via other clients stand for direct access to the nupkg file with HTTP client that is not identified as NuGet i.e. such tools can be used by third party services like [nudoq.org](http://www.nudoq.org/) or some search engines. But if you want to be sure you should ask at [Nuget discussion board](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions).

Comment: thanks for your answer that actually helps a little bit. Yeah unfortunately this question is asked in nuget discussion board by someone else and there is no response: http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/541088

Comment: @Hossein then maybe you could try other [contact options](http://www.nuget.org/policies/Contact) i.e. send an email to support@nuget.org

Answer (score 0):

[Answered by xavierdecoster on NuGetGallery issue here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3298)

> This is indeed based on the CDN data, but the clients are sending the user agent strings.
>
> Looked at the data, and the following User-Agents are having lots of requests without the NuGet-Operation HTTP Header.
> The CDN is configured to look for this custom HTTP-header, and when available, the data is parsed by the stats jobs collecting the info from the CDN W3C logs.